# Data structure in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, data-structures

```
names=['Peter', 'John']
size = ['X', 'M', 'L']
list_price =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  # There are 2 people will buy 3 size of shirt
```

I want to create my data structure into:

```
[
{'name': u'Peter', 'size_price': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, { 'X': 1, 'M':2, 'L': 3})}, 
{'name': 'John', 'size_price': defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'X':4, 'M':5, 'L':6})}
]
```

I prefer to do defaultdict()

Comment: What is your doubt? It is possible clearly.

Comment: Should we assume that each name just takes the next `len(size)` elements from `list_price`? It's simple enough to do, but it's not obvious from the starting structures that this is what's wanted.

Comment: Did you try something, below you have got a good answer and the you updates your question..

Comment: I don't think using a defaultdict makes much sense here. I guess you _could_ use a defaultdict to generate the next entry in the size_price sub-dict, but that will only work if you access those values in just the right order.

Comment: I just added my correct format!

Comment: As I said, using a defaultdict seems not to make any sense here. Are you planning to add further values to the sub-dicts later on? If so, what values would those have?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn `list_price` into an iterator and then use `next` to get one value after the other:

```
>>> iterator = iter(list_price)
>>> [{"name": n, "size_price": {s: next(iterator) for s in size}} for n in names]
[{'size_price': {'X': 1, 'M': 2, 'L': 3}, 'name': 'Peter'}, 
 {'size_price': {'X': 4, 'M': 5, 'L': 6}, 'name': 'John'}]
```

Of course you do not have to use a list comprehension but can do the same thing with nested loops as well.